# Optimal control of a Robot

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

I have a robot which moves abiding by the following equation:
$$
\frac{d^2 \mathbf{x}}{dt} = -k \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} + \mathbf{a}(t),
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a coordinate vector.
It starts with 
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = v_0,$$
and $\mathbf{x} = (x0, y0, z0)$. 
I need to find vector valued acceleration function $\mathbf{a}(t)$, which gets robot into spot with coordinates $(0,0,0)$ the quietest way possible.

I'm not sure how to correctly write my target functional which to minimise.

It seems that my target functional is 
$$
\frac{\partial \int_{t=0}^{t=\tau}\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}dt }{\partial \tau} = 0,
$$ 
where $\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}$ computed from solution of original differential equation with optimal $\mathbf{a}(t)$.
Because if $\tau$ is optimal, then first derivative with respect to $\tau$ necessary zero. But I'm not sure I've got it right, so I would appreciate a few hints and pointers to the literature.

Comment: Nice question. But does 'quietest' mean we want to minimize the integral of the absolute value (or square of the absolute value) of the acceleration? Correct? (Absolute value = norm.)

Comment: @peterag may be, but I'm not sure how to prove it strictly.